# Delegate for "View" for Push Notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, push-notification

Is there any delegate which gets called when we tap on the "View" button of Push Notification alert. This is when App is inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. It is `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. From the Apple docs:

> If the action button is tapped, the
>   system launches the application and
>   the application calls its delegate’s
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
>   method (if implemented); it passes in
>   the notification payload (for remote
>   notifications) or the
>   local-notification object (for local
>   notifications). If the application
>   icon is tapped, the application calls
>   the same method, but furnishes no
>   information about the notification.

Here is the reference: [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) Look at the **Handling Local and Remote Notifications** section.

Comment: is same delegate gets called for iOS 4(if application is in background state)? or wheather it calls one or both from following delegates applicationWillEnterForeground/applicationDidBecomeActive ?

Answer (score 0):

From a glance at the [Push Notification docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4), it looks like you get the notification in `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and can retrieve the notification info from the options dictionary using `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get notification payload when app is in background, because when icon is tapped applicationDidEnterForeground is called and in this method we cannot access launchOptions OR userInfo dictionary.