# push notification not invoking the method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, notifications

I have enabled the push notification for production in my app id , created the provisioning profile using it. When i run the app in my ipad it ask for notifications and i had on the corresponding notification. But the problem is the method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
```

is not invoking eventhough i had added the following code in the didfinishlaunch

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

Any idea please help me, i am using ios6 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just impliment like this way:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{



    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];

}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    self.strToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {

} 




- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {    
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
        NSString *showTitle = @"Show";
        NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"myapp name"
                                                            message:message 
                                                           delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];


    } else {
        //Do stuff that you would do if the application was not active
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

> In Device, Go to Settings->Notifications->YourApp->Enable_Notifications

and

please check bellow stack-overflow questions might be its helps you

[iOS Registering for Push Notifications within Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113716/ios-registering-for-push-notifications-within-application)

[Delegate for "View" for Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825156/delegate-for-view-for-push-notification)

[Push Notification delegate call backs are not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631710/push-notification-delegate-call-backs-are-not-getting-called)

[Push notification delegate method issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109373/push-notification-delegate-method-issue)

[push notification : both didFailToRegister and didRegister delegate not calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820566/push-notification-both-didfailtoregister-and-didregister-delegate-not-calling)

[Push Notification Delegates not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169201/push-notification-delegates-not-getting-called)

**EDIT**
Check in setting is there notification not turn off
[image]

Comment: i think there is invoking a this didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError please check using breakpoints  which method called..?

Comment: yes it is working on my iPhone not in my iPad , how to solve this issue

Comment: are you checking in setting ->pushnotification turn off as my edit answer check this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19858/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-user1523250)